# Or controller problem in GE

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

This is a very small question, and there is not much to explain; let me jump into it: I have my character with WSAD controls. When triggering any part of WSAD (using or controller), my animation plays. When I press A  and D, W and S, all the keys together, or any odd combo where you should not be moving (e.g. you move left and right using A and D, so you don't move), the walk animation plays. When you are not moving, you should not look like you are. How can I pass this? Should I just use an and controller for all the combos? I, for those of you who need my question in a sentence rather than context, just basically want my character to play his walk animation *only* when moving. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be best solved with a **Xor** controller. You need two of them. one for *W* and *S*, and one for *A* and *D*.
[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) is an example of a Xor gate.

[image]

Here is a [.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34058) example.

Comment: well-written, well-earned. Say, have you ever gave a shot at an FPS; you answer many of my questions. I just would love to see your work.

Comment: Most of what I do has a lot of great ideas that don't make it very far. I end up with a lot of games that just have cubes that I use for beta testing; as in this [2-person-sumo-wrestling game](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34060).

Comment: Yeah I have made many projects that I worked on until I disliked it; however, I made a project that I have enjoyed for 3 years in development, but I am a single 13 year old and made many problems so I haven't even passed finishing the controller. Your shaders are nice though

Comment: ahha. I didn't even make that one. got it off of BA.